# How do I create a LAS file coverage grid in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, lidar, lastools

I need to take a folder of .las files and create a coverage grid overview with an attribute for each las tile's file name within each polygon record, each polygon being the rectangle of that las file's extent.

I have tried using LASTools "boundaryPro" for this but am having troubles.  I have added -overview to combine the outputs into an overview grid and it works great but the las file names do not become attribute values in the output.  I have considered running this as a batch on the single files and then combining the vector outputs but in order to get those filenames into each output it requires a lot of field creating and field calculating and I have hundreds of .las files.

So am i missing something in the -overview process?  I have clicked on "create labels" but nothing seems to be generated for that.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also added -labels to the command line options and that seems to have populated the grid with everything i need, despite having the "Produce Labels" checkbox checked.

Answer (score 0):

lastools lasboundary should work fine.

If your up for using Python, the Whitebox library has a great function for creating a shapefile of footprints.
[LidarTileFootprint](https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/available_tools/lidar_tools.html#LidarTileFootprint)